# Предотвращение одновременного запуска нескольких AsyncTask

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask, mutex

Есть некий `AsyncTask`. Нужно предотвратить одновременное выполнение нескольких его экземпляров.

Есть идея использовать старый добрый `Mutex`, но насколько это правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `AsyncTask` есть метод [`executeOnExecutor (Executor exec, Params... params)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)), с помощью которого можно организовать поведение Ваших тасков.
Так же есть два заготовленных для этого `Executor`'а: [`SERIAL_EXECUTOR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) и [`THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
Если я правильно понял вопрос Вам нужен [`SERIAL_EXECUTOR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) - все таски запущенные такой командой будут выполняться по очереди

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params...);
```

Либо Вы можете создать свой, более подходящий экземпляр [`Executor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) и использовать его для организации задач.